# Как нарисовать UML диаграмму классов в приложении?

Tags: c++, objective-c, uml

Нужен инструмент создания и отрисовки UML-диаграмм классов в программе. Не по коду, а именно кодом. Может, кто знает подобную библиотеку, API на C++ или Objective-C?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405953/generating-uml-from-c-code

Comment: @rikimaru2013 вот совсем там другое! Мне нужна библиотека для создания и отрисовки диаграмм кодом в приложении, а не программа для конвертации ЮМЛ в код и обратно.

Comment: Боюсь, что такого инструмента попросту нет. Можно поискать инструмент, который построит граф отношений, по коду. А вот рисовать придётся самому, т.к. кто будет делать библиотеку отрисовки, когда канва для рисования отличается от ОС, к ОС и от библиотеки к библиотеке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать plantuml, dot (Graphviz). Первое Java, но можете попытаться портировать код на C++. Второе - генерить исходник в коде и скармливать его dot. В общем, это тот вариант, который бы использовал я.

Либо курить что-то вроде:

- http://www.ucancode.net/UML_DIAGRAM_DRAW_PRINT_GENERATE_SOURCE_CODE.htm
- https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cdebcc67-96fc-4d4c-9ca0-19e183147b00

Comment: Я так надеялся, что будет ответ лучше. Какой рекомендацией воспользовались?

Comment: извиняюсь, раньше комментария не видел. Я решил перейти на C# и вызывать Graphviz (для этого нашёл и чуть подправил неплохой wrapper). Далеко не идеально, но работает без проблем.